# Telnet disconnects too quickly for HTTP commands on port 80

Tags: windows-7, telnet

My home router provides Web server here: 10.1.1.1:80

I can ping and connect to it fine with a web browser. For whatever reason, I want to establish a connection to its **web server** via telnet too.

I have installed telnet on windows 7. I run cmd as admin.
I run telnet, and set localecho.
I then open 10.1.1.1 80

The result always leads to the connection not occurring:

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet> open 10.1.1.1 80
Connecting To 10.1.1.1...

Connection to host lost.
```

I have used wireshark to confirm that an exchange of packets between the telnet client and the webserver was in fact occurring to rule out any firewall issues (there was no payload, but the server was sending back ACKs). Am I missing something? Why can't I submit HTTP commands?

I want to know how to use telnet to send and receive the http requests. For reasons outside the scope, I have to use telnet as the tool.

EDIT: I think telnet is working ok but the server is just disconnecting too quickly for me to submit any HTTP commands. I tried with a number of servers and noticed that, in most cases, there is no feasible way to submit a command (i.e. the connection is lost before a single key press can be made). So I suppose what I should have asked (updated the title accordingly) is:

(a) why is it lost so quickly?

and

(b) what can be done to either not lose the connection or submit a command before the connection is lost?

Comment: Have you tried using port 23?

Comment: I am not trying to make a telnet connection, I am trying to test the web server on port 80 using telnet. Sorry I should have made that clearer.

Comment: How long of a period is it between `Connecting To 10.1.1.1...` and `Connection to host lost.`

Comment: Almost instant. I get a Press any key... almost as soon as it forms the connection. In fact, I can see in wireshark that it is 1.1 seconds. That is from first packet to last.

Comment: Are you attempting the telnet operation from a machine on which `http://10.1.1.1/` is 100% known to work?

Comment: Yes. If I use a web browser from the same machine, it happily shows me an html page.

Comment: Does this happen with all connections to port 80 (e.g., other servers)? If not, then perhaps the router's web server is configured with an incredibly short read timeout.

Comment: It doesn't happen with all servers, but it happens with quite a few, I noticed. Is there potentially something else making him close it so quickly. What are other differences are there between accessing port 80 via telnet versus a web browser?

Comment: What is the *exact* URL that works on the machine where `telnet 10.1.1.1 80` does not?

Comment: I can do "telnet www.google.com 80" and it works: that is what I meant. All the addresses "work" in the sense that I get a TCP/IP response from the remote host. But some addresses, quite a few, disappear almost instantly. It is not clear to me why the remote server is closing the socket in the first place.

Comment: It's probably because the HTTPd expects an automated response from a client, rather than a human user typing out a query. If you don't send a query fast enough, it closes the connection. HTTP servers are busy; humans are a waste of their time. ;)

Comment: Can this be demonstrated? Where is this timeout set?